# How to Average text in Excel

Tags: excel, analysis

I just ran an IF function in Excel to compare ( Current (Y,N) vs Proposed (Y,N) results within 2 columns how do I avg the result now in 1 column mathematically (ex. percentage)?

Comment: Please be more specific about how your data is laid out. Have you tried simply using the AVERAGE function?

Comment: I have 1 column refecting  Y and  N (text) and im looking to get an avg of the entire population.

Comment: Can you you put in a sample of your data layout?  (Use four spaces at the beginning of a line to make your table monospaced.)

Answer (score 2):

`COUNTA` and `COUNTIF` will get you to where you need

Assuming the list is in A2:A1000 -

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A1000,"Y")/COUNTA(A2:A1000)
```

This will give the ratio of Yes answers to all answers. If you wanted to know what people responded, then you could either present it as **xx% voted Yes** or check the value against 0.5, and if less than 0.5, **Majority Voted No**, if greater than 0.5, **Majority Voted Yes**, and finally, if equal to 0.5, **Tied**

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in Excel `AVERAGE(cell1,cell2...)`. Make sure you are highlighting the proper cells. You can highlight both columns.

Comment: I have 1 column refecting Y and N (text) and im looking to get an avg of the entire population.

Comment: Select another cell where you want to average to be, type in `AVERAGE(`, then select the cells you want to be averaged (by clicking one and then dragging your cursor over the rest). Then close parentheses `)`. Hope this helps